# Micronaut Petstore port conflicts

Tags: micronaut

I'm following the order of startup the documentation recommends. After starting console and the databases with docker-compose, I then start the pets app:

`./gradlew pets:run`

It starts up on port:8080.

I then start the vendors app:

`./gradlew vendors:run`

This produces the following error: Error starting Micronaut server: Unable to start Micronaut server on port: 8080.

Comment: We are aware that the instructions for running the project needs to be updated.  There are also some timing issues when using `docker-compose` to start them up that need to be resolved.  This question doesn't appear to be a programming question though.  Our Gitter is a good place to discuss stuff like that.  https://gitter.im/micronautfw/

Comment: This isn't really a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

pets, vendors, comments, mail, and offers are not configured to select a random port. It seems that Micronaut defaults to port:8080. So the first one up wins. Add this line to the application.properties or application.groovy file in the resource folder:

`micronaut.server.port= -1`

Offers uses .yml configuration, add this server configuration to the application.yml in the resources folder:

`micronaut:
  application:
    name: offers
  server:
    port: -1`

With the -1 configuration Micronaut will communicate with the OS and select random available port.

The databases and Storefront are configured with fixed ports.

Comment: Works flawless for me! Thanks